# C illegal instruction

Tags: c, x86-64, undefined-behavior, illegal-instruction

Below is a print out of a c program I wrote, a demonstration of me running it, and finally some information on my compiler.

```
➜  illegalInstructionDebug cat illegal.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void func(int* Z){
    Z[-11] = acos(2);
}

int main(){
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("");
    fflush(stdout);
    int X[3];
    int Z[3];
    for (int n=0;0!=0;);
    func(Z);
}
➜  illegalInstructionDebug gcc illegal.c; ./a.out
[1]    28836 illegal hardware instruction  ./a.out
➜  illegalInstructionDebug clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
➜  illegalInstructionDebug
```

I was writing a program an encountered an illegal instruction error, which is something I had never seen before, so I decided to attempt to find a minimal working example so I could figure out what distinguished it from a segfault or some other kind of error. Oddly, it seemed minor changes in the program would return it to giving a segfault instead of an illegal instruction error. Nonetheless, I have managed to reduce the program down substantially to a smaller working example. That being said, the program is still rather large for a minimal working example.

My questions are first why am I getting an illegal instruction error and second what is an illegal instruction error. Also if this error is specific to my machine that would interest me also. There are a lot of strange attributes to this program. For example, it seems the number -11 is required to cause the error.

Comment: You are most likely overwriting a return address, which causes the processor to fetch the middle bytes of an instruction.

Comment: More generally speaking you are trying to explain "undefined behaviour". When your program has UB it can seg fault, get an illegal instruction error, appear to work or any other behaviour. It's not productive to try and explain why `-10` causes behaviour X and `-11` causes behaviour Y. That's not to criticise any desire to understand what "illegal instruction" means but just to be aware that the general concept of trying to explain UB for particular set of conditions is unproductive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that trying to understand undefined behaviour is not worth doing. In this case, I would like to know what an illegal instruction is and how it is created.

Comment: For that, may I suggest searching for "illegal instruction error" on SO and internet in general would be productive.

Comment: If you compile a program the compiler converts the C code to hardware instructions.  Each kind of computer and operating system does things differently so the compiler can only guarantee what will happen if there is no undefined behaviour.  If a function writes to memory that isn't inside a variable then it could overwrite something important to the program or operating system.  For example, if a function overwrites the return address then when the function returns it can jump anywhere.  But what happens depends on where the compiler and operating system store stuff and how the hardware works.

Comment: So, we would need to know the exact version of your compiler and the compiler command line and what exact version of which operating system you have and the exact model of your CPU and where exactly your program was loaded in memory and (if your hardware doesn't have an MMU that protects memory) what was loaded in memory in the pages surrounding your program.  Basically it's impossible to predict what will happen unless you have a complete memory snapshot along will all that other info.  Basically the same problems any assembly language programmer has every day!

Comment: one cause of "illegal instruction" errors is the compiler emitting `ud2` or similar when it detects undefined behaviour at compile-time

Comment: @M.M: That was my first thought, too, but looks like GCC and clang don't spot the UB at compile time or at least don't react to it that way; https://godbolt.org/z/sxdrdx shows mainline clang not emitting any `ud2` or fall-through function bodies, even after inlining the function into the caller.  OP must have compiled with optimization disabled because the optimized `main` just calls `acos` without doing anything with the return value.  No stray writes to stack memory.  So I guess optimizing away dead stores happened before UB detection.

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277486). Specifically: "It is important to investigate the cause of the undefined behavior - not so much the symptoms. Beginners often ask why a certain behavior occurred when they did something undefined, but there is often not much to learn from investigating the outcome. Time is better spent on learning what caused the undefined behavior."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
void func(int *Z){
    Z[-11] = acos(2);
}
```

most likely happens to overwrite some *code* address in the stack. Most likely a return address. Since the stack grows down on x86-64, and you're writing to stuff to lower address, it would mean a return address that was placed on stack *after* space for `Z` was reserved, so I suppose this would hit the return address from `func()`. And more importantly, you would be overwriting *half* of the return address.

`acos(2)` is a domain error, and returns NaN, which converted to `int` on my GCC results in `INT_MIN` being written there... You should actually use the debugger and see the context where the crash happens, I would guess it is at an address that contains lots of `f`s in its hex representation.

And invalid instruction is raised when the bytes starting from RIP do not decode to a valid x86-64 instruction, or [for other reasons](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-212.html).

Comment: In case someone is interested in trying to debug it, this may help http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html